# How to plot interaction effects from extremely large data sets (esp. from rxGlm output)

Tags: r, glm, microsoft-r

I am currenlty computing `glm` models off a huge data data set. Both `glm` and even `speedglm` take days to compute.

I currently have around 3M observations and altogether 400 variables, only some of which are used for the regression. In my regression I use 4 integer independent variables (`iv1`, `iv2`, `iv3`, `iv4`), 1 binary independent variable as factor (`iv5`), the interaction term (`x * y`, where `x` is an integer and `y` is a binary dummy variable as factor). Finally, I have fixed effects along years `ff1` and company ids `ff2`. I have 15 years and 3000 conmpanies. I have introduced the fixed effects by adding them as factors. I observe that especially the 3000 company fixed effects make the computation very slow in `stats` `glm` and also `speedglm`.

I therefore decided to try Microsoft R's `rxGlm` (RevoScaleR), as this can address more threads and processor cores. Indeed, the speed of analysis is a lot faster. Also, I compared the results for a sub-sample to the one of standard `glm` and they matched.

I used the following function:

```
mod1 <- rxGlm(formula = dv ~ 
                      iv1 + iv2 + iv3+ 
                      iv4 + iv5 +
                      x * y +
                      ff1  + ff2,
                    family = binomial(link = "probit"), data = dat,
                    dropFirst = TRUE, dropMain = FALSE, covCoef = TRUE, cube = FALSE)
```

However, I am facing a problem when trying to plot the interaction term using the `effects` package. Upon calling the following function, I am receiving the following error:

```
> plot(effect("x*y", mod1))
Error in terms.default(model) : no terms component nor attribute
```

I assume the problem is that `rxGlm` does not store the data needed to plot the interaction. I believe so because the `rxGlm` object is a lot smaller than the `glm` oject, hence likely containing less data (80 MB vs several GB).

I now tried to convert the `rxGlm` object to `glm` via `as.glm()`. Still, the `effects()` call does not yield a result and results in the following error messages:

```
Error in dnorm(eta) : 
  Non-numerical argument for mathematical function
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In model.matrix.default(mod, data = list(dv = c(1L, 2L,  :
  variable 'x for y' is absent, its contrast will be ignored
```

If I now compare an original glm to the "converted glm", I find that the converted glm contains a lot less items. E.g., it does not contain `effects` and for contrasts it states only `contr.treatment` for each variable.

I am now looking primarily for a way to transpose the `rxGlm` output object in a format so I can use if with the `effect()` function. If there is no way to do so, how can I get an interaction plot using functions within the `RevoScaleR` package, e.g., `rxLinePlot()`? `rxLinePlot()` also plots reasonably quick, however, I have not yet found a way how to get typical interaction effect plots out of it. I want to avoid first calculating the full `glm` model and then plot because this takes very long.

Comment: How big is the dataset, and do you have a data sample?

Comment: @Technophobe01 I have added more information on the data right into the question (second paragraph). Given that my question is more about amount of data and less about a specific data problem, I think posting a sample of my data would make little sense. Posting the data set in its entirity would not be possible due to confidentiality and size of the file.

Comment: If each variable is 40 kilobytes and you have 400 variables and 3,000,000 million observations you're dealing with roughly 48Tb of data. Correct? Bigger or Smaller? My point is your output of 80mb doesn't sound quite right to the dataset size. Caveat - a rule of thumb estimate.

Comment: Let me see if I can pull an example together using a sizable public data set. Might be fun to a comparison between MSFT R, Tibco TERR and Open R.

Comment: No, the data set is smaller. If loaded into the R workspace the data frame is around 9gb. The stats glm on this data is around 40gb. The rxGlm file only a couple of MB.

Comment: [Smiles] - I'd remove "huge" form you dataset description.  Don't take that the wrong way I am chuckling as I say it. Joking aside - thanks for updating the answer.

Comment: No worries :) - I’m well aware there are way larger data sets than that. The thing is even in a cloud instance it takes 1.5 weeks to compute the GLM which is why I’m trying to handle somehow

Comment: Quick question what is your OS preference Windows, Ubuntu, Centos, Redhat or MacOS X?

Comment: I’m working with Windows 64 bit

Comment: Try h2o package.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the coefficients can't you just roll your own? 
This would *not* be a dataset size issue

```
# ex. data
n = 2000
dat <- data.frame( dv = sample(0:1, size = n, rep = TRUE), 
                   iv1 = sample(1:10, size = n, rep = TRUE),
                   iv2 = sample(1:10, size = n, rep = TRUE),
                   iv3 = sample(1:10, size = n, rep = TRUE),
                   iv4 = sample(0:10, size = n, rep = TRUE),
                   iv5 = as.factor(sample(0:1, size = n, rep = TRUE)),
                   x = sample(1:100, size = n, rep = TRUE),
                   y = as.factor(sample(0:1, size = n, rep = TRUE)),
                   ff1  = as.factor(sample(1:15, size = n, rep = TRUE)),
                   ff2  = as.factor(sample(1:100, size = n, rep = TRUE))
                   )

mod1 <- glm(formula = dv ~ 
                      iv1 + iv2 + iv3+ 
                      iv4 + iv5 +
                      x * y +
                      ff1  + ff2,
                    family = binomial(link = "probit"), data = dat)

# coefficients for x, y and their interaction
x1 <- coef(mod1)['x']
y1 <- coef(mod1)['y1']
xy <- coef(mod1)['x:y1']

x <- 1:100
a <- x1*x
b <- x1*x + y1 + xy*x

plot(a~x, type= 'line', col = 'red', xlim = c(0,max(x)), ylim = range(c(a, b)))
lines(b~x, col = 'blue')
legend('topright', c('y = 0', 'y = 1'), col = c('red', 'blue'))
```

[image: here is how to make a reproduceable]