# Interaction effect plots with speedglm output

Tags: r, glm, speedglm

I am working with a dataset large enough to make necessary the use of alogorithms more advanced than `stats` `glm` in order to compute binomial regression models. `glm` takes over a week to compute.

[Large fixed effects binomial regression in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634040/large-fixed-effects-binomial-regression-in-r/39216738#39216738) suggests `rxGlm` and `speedglm`. I tried both and managed to achieve significant improvements in speed (down to under 2 hours). However, I am facing the following problem:

In both cases, I cannot use the `effects` function `plot(effect())` to create **interaction plots** similar to the following ones, because `effects` cannot deal with these kind of objects and / or needed data is missing.

[image: Sample interaction effect plot]

I already had posted a question with bounty on `rxGlm` ([How to plot interaction effects from extremely large data sets (esp. from rxGlm output)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080343/how-to-plot-interaction-effects-from-extremely-large-data-sets-esp-from-rxglm)), to no avail. So I guess there is no way to do so using `rxGlm`.

Now my question: can I **plot such interaction effect terms using `speedglm`**, and if so, how?